# Append textarea with carriage return and post

Tags: javascript

I've a form where I need to append a textarea that is OUTSIDE the form.

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="text" name="txt1" value="some value">
   <input type="text" name="txt2" value="some value">
   ...

   <button type="submit" id="btn" value="SUBMIT">
</form>


    <textarea id="textarea">TEST OUTSIDE FORM
    WITH CARRIAGE RETURN</textarea>
```

Using this is ok but carriage is not preserved:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $("#textarea").val();
  var form = $("#form");
  form.append($('<input>', {'name': 'textarea', 'value': value, 'type': 'hidden' }) );
  form.submit();
```

I tried using:

```
 form.append($('<textarea>', {'name': 'textarea', 'value': value }) );
});
```

But in this case nothing is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
form.append($('<textarea name="textarea1">'+ value +'</textarea>') );
```

You can add carriage return sign to your text by adding: `\\\r`